# Can a compiler optimize classes to be "inlined"?

Tags: kotlin, dart, compilation

Some programming languages have the `inline` or other keyword to manual specify a function call site to be replaced with the body of the called function.

C# for example does not have this, because the compiler automatically decides which code gets inlined, avoiding, in my opinion, polluting the developer experience (developers shouldn't be worrying about optimizations).

Some languages implemented a syntax to `inline` classes like Kotlin and now Dart, which wrap an existing type into a new static type, reducing the overhead of a tradicional class.

Dart declaration example (specificated, not yet implemented):

```dart
inline class Foo {
  // A single instance variable, defining the representation type.
  final Bar bar;
  
  // The desired set of other members.
  void function1() {
     bar.baz; 
  }
  ...
}
```

My question is, could a compiler make this optimization automatically in classes? If not, what challenges make this difficult/impossible?

Comment: I don't think that compiler always know if inlining a class improves performance. If it does not, there is no point in it

Answer (score 2):

It is not only about optimisation.  Some inlining could make the resultant code less performant and/or larger, so Kotlin gives you control. (IntelliJ warnings against inlining in some cases - warning you that it won't improve performance.)

More than that, you should read about [Reified Type Parameters](https://kotlinlang.org/docs/inline-functions.html#reified-type-parameters) - this allows for certain coding techniques that are only possible when the function is inlined as well as the type information.

Here is some code that is impossible in Java:

Suppose you have a series of enums, representing states of an Object, e.g.

```kotlin
enum class Color {RED,BLUE,GREEN}
enum class Size {SMALL,MEDIUM,LARGE}
data class MyObject(val color: Color, val size:Size)
```

and you had a test data generator that uses an Random number generator to pick a random enum for the Object.

In Kotlin you can write:

```kotlin
val rnd = Random(1)
val x = MyObject(
    color = getRandomEnum(rnd),
    size = getRandomEnum(rnd),
)
```

Using this

```kotlin
private inline fun <reified T : Enum<T>> getRandomEnum(rnd: Random): T {
    val values: Array<T> = enumValues()
    return values.get(rnd.nextInt(values.size))
}
```

Comment: I understand this statement "Some inlining could make the resultant code less performant", however, like many others optimizations I would think the compiler would apply some heuristic. 

Also, maybe this applies to Kotlin, but some languages (like Dart) can always perform this check `variable is T`, without resorting to inline capabilities, so I think that's more a JVM limitation/side effect.

Comment: Another feature that's only available in inlined functions is [non-local returns](https://kotlinlang.org/docs/inline-functions.html#non-local-returns). And inlining [affects binary compatibility](https://kotlinlang.org/docs/inline-functions.html#restrictions-for-public-api-inline-functions). So whether a function is inlined affects its semantics, as well as its performance — that's why it must be specified explicitly.